# How to get date from milliseconds

Tags: java, date

Hi All I have a requirement where i need to check date with system date value but the date value i have in DB is in milliseconds so below are my code but the problem is the system date which i get display month value incorrect its display month value one month less .

```
    Date now = new Date();
    Long nowLong = now.getTime() / 1000;
    Integer unixTime = nowLong.intValue();

    Calendar cal;
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(unixTime * 1000L);

    Integer day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Integer month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    Integer hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    Integer minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    String amPm = (cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM) ? "PM" : "AM";
    Integer year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    System.out.println("day :" + day);
    System.out.println("month :" + month);
    System.out.println("hour " + hour);
    System.out.println("minute " + minute);
    System.out.println("amPm " + amPm);
    System.out.println("year " + year);
```

For this the output is 
day :3
month :4
hour 3
minute 13
amPm PM
year 2016
but output is not correct . Can any one help me .

Comment: When you say the output is not correct - what were you expecting the output to be?

Comment: (i) Why do you convert from epoch millis to epoch seconds then back to epoch millis? (i) Why do you use objects instead of primitives?

Comment: Don't use `Integer` instead of `int`. In general, don't use `Date` or `Calendar` either. Use the date / time API ([`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/index.html)).

Comment: @user3279506 Exactly what is your question, what is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

In Java the value returned by `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)`is **zero bazed**. Thenf `JANUARY = 0`, `FEBRUARY = 0`, ... (documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.JANUARY))

Try this :

```
Integer month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

Or this :

```
System.out.println("month :" + (month.intValue() + 1));
```

Note the creation of your calendar can be simpler:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: For Java **`Calendar`** the value returned by `get(Calendar.MONTH)` for januari is 0. Java as a language doesn't define JANUARI. Point in case: [`Month.getValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getValue--)

Answer (score 0):

try using LocalDate . there has been lot of changes to Date Time api in java 8 .you can do it better with LocalDate.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(); //current date
today.getMonth() //getMonth as a string
today.getMonth()//getMonthValue in an int
today.getDayOfWeek() // get the date in a string format
today.getDayOfMonth() //get the date as an int.
today.getYear()//get the year
```